# How to dynamically adjust a range in a calculation in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel formula `=SUM(AZ2:AZ300)`

I want to make this more dynamic by using the formula `=ROW(OFFSET($B$1,COUNTA($B:$B)-1,0))` in cell A1

Then I want my formula to do the following `=SUM(AZ2:AZ&A1)`
This formula doesn't work, but it to take the sum of cells AZ2 through AZ and the number given in cell A1

For example if A1 value is 250 then I want the formula to be equivalent to `=SUM(AZ2:AZ250)`

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than putting the row number in a separate cell you could combine it in the formula:
`=SUM($A$2:INDEX($A:$A,COUNTA($B:$B)-1))`

This does the same as the `OFFSET` version, with the bonus of not being volatile.